# adding background images in js file for website

Tags: javascript, html

```
         document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/background52.jpg')";<br>
```

I tried in this way.but it is not working properly.

Comment: Why is there a `<br>` after the semicolon? That should cause an error. Also, try hitting F12 and clicking on "Console" in your browser (assuming Chrome) to see if it displays any errors

Comment: Can you post more than that simple snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a html tag `<br>` in your javascript, see the console and you will see an error like

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Get rid of `<br>` and it will work.